# why is it a bad idea to have << operator in a global namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading

I have this code and i can't understand how it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<int, double> elem_t;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, elem_t p)
{
  return os << p.first << ',' << p.second;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<elem_t> v(10);
  std::cout << v[0] << '\n';
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<elem_t>(std::cout, " "));
  return 0;
}
```

when line `std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<elem_t>(std::cout, " "));` is comented it works just fine, but when it's not i get a lot of wornings and errors. What is the difference between how this lines work?

```
std::cout << v[0] << '\n';
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<elem_t>(std::cout, " "));
```

I tried looking into namespaces and overloading << operator, but i still don't get the mechanics of ostream_iterator and why it's not compiling without errors.

Comment: In this case I would say yes. You have an alias elem_t for a std::pair, so any pair with the same signature would match the operator overload. My advice never use std::pair outside template programming, just make an explicit struct with 2 members. You will then have a strong type (not an alias) which will improve your code quality and readability (you will get tired of looking up what first/second members of pair actually mean)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the global namespace scope. The rule is: 1. Only overload operators if they depend in some way on a type you own. 2. If you do overload an operator put it in the exact same namespace scope that the type that you own belongs to. That's the only way to get the operator to behave as expected in all contexts.

Comment: *why is it a bad idea to have `<<` operator in a global namespace?*  **i get a lot of warnings and errors**.  Although that's because of ADL, not because of `<<` in the global namespace.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bad idea to write operator functions for types you do not "own" (i.e., don't contain any of your user types).

`std::pair<int, double>` and `std::ostream` only have types in the `std` namespace (`int` and `double` don't have any associated namespaces). When the compiler tries to look up an `operator<<` to output when outputting to `std::ostream_iterator`, it cannot be found in the global namespace (See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

If you use one of your own types instead:

```cpp
struct elem_t : std::pair<int, double> {
    using pair::pair;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, elem_t p)
{
  return os << p.first << ',' << p.second;
}
```

... It will work just fine since `operator<<` and `elem_t` are defined in the same namespace (and it can be found via ADL)